# How to toggle the anchor text using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```
<label for="LoginControl">
<a href="login/" class="concealed noOutline">  Log in or Sign up  </a>
</label>
```

I need to replace the text Log in or Sign up with X when it is clicked and return to old text when clicked again.

Comment: IS it going to a different page when you click it?

Comment: It has an href to login with no click event, so i'm guessing it takes them to a login page.  Unless he has a global jQuery catch for link clicking.

Comment: It works similar to this http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a click handler for your anchor:

```
$("a.concealed").click(function() {
```

Now you'll need some logic:

```
$(this).text() == "X" ? "Log in or Sign up" : "X"; //if it equals X, return Log. Else X.
```

Now just combine into a function:

```
$("a.concealed").click(function() {
    var newText = $(this).text() == "X" ? "Log in or Sign up" : "X";
    $(this).text(newText);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/afuub/

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you give your a tag an id

```
<label for="LoginControl"><a id="myLink" href="login/" class="concealed noOutline">Log in or Sign up</a></label>
```

and then this is how you can do it: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHbz2/)

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
    <label for="LoginControl">
     <a href="login/" class="concealed noOutline">  Log in or Sign up  </a>
    </label>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $('label a').click(function(
        $(this).toggle(
               function(){$(this).text('X')},
               function(){$(this).text('Login or Sign Up')}
   )}
```

Read more on Jquery Toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: This only toggles once.

Comment: This executed the once and hides anchor after toggle